# Como identificar los valores que trae Log.e en Android con Firebase

Tags: java, android, android-studio, firebase, if

Tengo esta estructura en Firebase 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y estoy llamando los ultimos tres datos con el nombre "dosis" con esta estructura

```
 my.child("usuario").orderByKey().limitToLast(3).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    for(DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        usuario us =snapshot.getValue(usuario.class);

                        Log.e("Datos: " , "" + us.getDosis());
                    }


                }
```

en el debug aparecen

E/Datos:: 160
E/Datos:: 12
          130

pero requiero identificarlos y compararlos en un if y generar el resultado y mostrarlo en pantalla.
Alguien sabe como podria hacerlos , Gracias.

Comment: en que sentido necesitas identificarlos en un if ? comparar uno con otro ?, los de la foto son los 3 primeros, los que trae esa query son los ultimos 3

Comment: Si señor compararlos

Comment: o pueden ser los ultimos dos

Comment: exactamente identificar el mayo

Comment: no no en la foto esta como para mostrar la estructura , pero ya revise y en los resultados si son los ultimos

Comment: Gastón Saillén Amigo sabes como ayudarme?

Comment: @Gastón Saillén

Comment: perdon, no estaba en casa, ahi lo veo

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Lo que podes hacer es guardar esos datos en un ArrayList y despues los usas

```
    my.child("usuario").orderByKey().limitToLast(3).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                          ArrayList<String> dosis = new ArrayList();
                        for(DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                            usuario us =snapshot.getValue(usuario.class);
                             dosis.add(us.getDosis());
                            Log.e("Datos: " , "" + us.getDosis());
                        }

                    //Despues accede a los datos del array
                     String valor1 = dosis.get(0);
                     String valor2 = dosis.get(1);
                     String valor3 = dosis.get(2);

                        //Parseamos los datos
                           int valorDosis1 = Integer.parseInt(valor1);
                           int valorDosis2 = Integer.parseInt(valor2);
                           int valorDosis3 = Integer.parseInt(valor3);

                       //Comparar el mayor de las 3 dosis

                         if(valorDosis1>valorDosis2 && valorDosis1>valorDosis3){
                           //valorDosis1 mayor
                       }else{
                           //valorDosis3 mayor
                        }if(valorDosis2 > valorDosis1 && valorDosis2 > valorDosis3){

                         //valorDosis2 mayor
                            }else{
                           //valorDosis3Mayor
                        }

                    }
```

Con eso te deberia funcionar bien y calcular el mayor de 3 dosis

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84126/discussion-on-answer-by-gaston-saillen-como-identificar-los-valores-que-trae-log).

Comment: gracias @Jorgesys , ya se habia hecho muy largo jaja, un saludo !

Comment: Me puedes ayudar con esto https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/209025/android-studio-bar-chart-graficar por fa